# Jasmine - test the $mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I need to cover this service 100% in jasmine test but it didn't let me cover the controller.

Here's the service for dialog:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('core.dialog').service('dialog', ToasterService);

    ToasterService.$inject = ['$translate', '$mdDialog'];

    function ToasterService($translate, $mdDialog) {

        this.show = function (key, values) {
            $translate(key, values).then(function (message, $event) {
                $mdDialog.show({
                    controller: DialogController,
                    templateUrl: 'app/common/core/dialog/dialog.html',
                    targetEvent: $event,
                    locals: {
                        message : message
                    }
                });

                function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, message) {
                    $scope.message = message;
                    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
                        $mdDialog.hide();
                    };
                }

            });
        };

    }

})();
```

but when I run the code coverage report it didn't cover the DialogController function.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case anyone is wondering how this might be solved, here is a way, one of several. I would create the controller with angular, move it out of the service, so you can unit test only the controller. Then spyOn $mdDialog.hide and make sure it was called. Assuming the DialogController(...) is moved out of service so it is visible.

```
angular.module('example')
       .controller('DialogController' DialogController);
```

Then, when setting up your test store $mdDialog for spying later, you also need $q or whatever promises you want to use if you are doing anything with the promise returned from hide().

```
var mdDialog, q;
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
        mdDialog = $injector.get("$mdDialog");
        q = $injector.get("$q");
```

Then you create your controller and $rootScope.$digest(), which is covered [elsewhere](http://angulartestingquickstart.com/) in-depth.
And finally in your tests:

```
spyOn(mdDialog, 'hide').and.callFake(function(){
        var deferred = q.defer();
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
      });
 // TODO: call your closeDialog() controller function here (may need to call $apply)
 expect(mdDialog.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
```